# Binding params for PDO statement inside a loop doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'd like to insert data to my database using `bindParam`.

Here is a shorter version of my code:

```
$reindex['f_name'] = 'Tom';
$reindex['l_name'] = 'Riddle';
$reindex['date'] = '2020-12-12';

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (f_name, l_name, date) VALUES (:f_name, :l_name, :date)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

foreach ($reindex as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . '<br>'; // look at output
    echo $value . '<br><br>';
    $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

Output of echo:

```
f_name
Tom

l_name
Riddle
```

I don't get any error messages. I set error reporting like this:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This would work but I have to define every bind separately:

```
$stmt->execute([
    'f_name' => $reindex['f_name'],
    'l_name' => $reindex['l_name'],
    'date' => $reindex['date']
]);
```

Comment: The output of the echo shows `f_name` (matches), `last_name` (does not match `l_name`), and there's no `date`. Always make sure that all of your parameters are bound correctly.

Comment: Also, [bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) binds the specific variable name, which in this case is `$key`. You want [bindValue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply this from the PDO manual

#### PDOStatement::bindParam

> Binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark placeholder in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the statement. Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.

You will understand that in your loop you are using the same variable X times. Overwriting it each time round the loop.

So when the actual binding is done, at the time you `->execute()` your prepared query, you only have one value, the last from your loop in those variables

Comment: oh alright, and how can I achieve the same with `bindParam`? Is it even possible to use this in a loop somehow?

Comment: I solved it using &value in the loop ;). Thanks for your hint!